# Propositional logic, logical equivalent

Tags: math, logic, logical-operators, discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

a)  Determine whether the following statement forms are logically equivalent:
p -> (q -> r) and (p -> q) -> r

b)   Use the logical equivalence established in part (a) to rewrite the following sentence in two different ways. (Assume that n represents a fixed integer.)
If n is prime, then n is odd or n is 2.

Can someone help me with the B one? its really confusing

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like homework and shows no effort.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this belongs to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

```
If n is prime, then n is odd or n is 2.
```

The question is asking you to rewrite the sentence in two different ways in English

```
If n is prime and n is not odd, then n is 2.
If n is prime and n is not 2, then n is odd.
```

The following links do a better job of explaining it:

[Logically_Equivalent_Statements](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Mathematical_Logic_and_Proof/Book:_Mathematical_Reasoning__Writing_and_Proof_(Sundstrom)/2:_Logical_Reasoning/2.2:_Logically_Equivalent_Statements)

[Exercises on Logic of Compound Statements and Valid Arguments](https://cs.gmu.edu/%7Ecarlotta/teaching/INFS-501/logic1.pdf)

Comment: @Sagechan if this answered your question, you should select it as the answer (green check mark)